# Creating a release web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, web-config-transform

im new to this transformations, and I dont full understand how to implement it. None of the guides make sense.

I want to add

```
 <identity impersonate="true" userName="asecret" password="mysecurepassword"/>
```

To the release config.

I put it in web.release.config after `<system.web>` but it does not generate as so.

What else are you suppose to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably missing the actual action to take place using the `xdt:Transform` attribute.

Try:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="asecret" password="mysecurepassword" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
```

The `Insert` should add the new element into the web.config under the `<system.web>` section.

If the `<identity />` element already exists in the main web.config file, you probably need to use `xdt:Transform="Replace"` which will replace the entire element in the main web.config with the one in your Web.Release.config. Or you can use `xdt:Transform="SetAttribute({comma listed attributes to set here})"`, which will set the value of the attributes you specify.

As always, you can read all the options for transformations on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx).

Comment: Thanks :) `Insert` worked. I had tried it previously with `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" `. It makes sense now. Bit of a silly question really, but saved me a lot of time. thanks.